# How to use kendo ui core with webpack and es2016?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, webpack

I am using the following boilerplate https://github.com/casufi/NG6-starter
Here is the part of app.js

```
        import $ from 'jquery';
        import angular from 'angular';
        import 'kendo-ui-core';
```

http://pastebin.com/raw/tgdp0UMR

But I get the following error message

> Error: The Kendo UI directives require jQuery to be available before AngularJS. Please include jquery before angular in the document.

Comment: Read the error. It's pretty clear how to fix it

Comment: I understood that I have to place jquery before angular and I changed code to

        import $ from 'jquery';
        import angular from 'angular';
        import 'kendo-ui-core';

The easiest way is to place link to jquery into index.html directly, but I want to do this in a proper way for https://github.com/casufi/NG6-starter

Comment: Have jQuery first and Angular second. The error is pretty clear about that.

Comment: Same error? I highly doubt it is, the error is telling you to import jQuery first

Comment: The Kendo UI directives require jQuery to be available before AngularJS. Please include jquery before angular in the document.

http://pastebin.com/raw/tgdp0UMR

Comment: The easiest way is to place link to jquery into index.html directly, but I want to do this in a proper way for https://github.com/casufi/NG6-starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1932

```
// ...
module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig () {
    var config = {};

    // ...

    config.plugins = [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ];

    // ...

    return config;
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

When kendo ui uses it's own template system, it needs `$` on the window. If you can, use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader
But if expose loader still doesn't work, then you have to create a module will place jquery on the `window`

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.$ = $
```

and have that module load first and before importing kendo

Answer (score 0):

It seems that current versions of kendo-ui-core are configured to use a version of jquery less than 3.0.0. If the rest of your project is using a higher version that that kendo-ui-core will be set up to have its own private version, hence the error.

A solution is to use an alias to force kendo-ui-core to use the same version of jquery as everyone else.

Try this in your webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery"), 
  },
  modules: ["node_modules"]
}
```